# Multi select files with Bootstrap and jQuery - code inside

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, file, user-interface

I'm using an example of how to attach files, but I'd like to know how I can attach multiple files in that code

I tried to use the multiple = "multiple" attribute, but it did not work. How would I adapt this code to accept multiple files?

The example I am using can be found here:

https://codepen.io/Sebus059/pen/MwMQbP

```
<div class="container">
    <h3>File Input Example</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label>Files:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group input-file" name="Fichier1">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-choose" multiple="multiple" type="button">Procurar </button>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder='Escolha um arquivo...' multiple="multiple" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-warning btn-reset" multiple="multiple" type="button">Remover</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Salvar</button>
        </div>
    </p>
</div>
```

Thats the script

```
<script>
    function bs_input_file() {
        $(".input-file").before(
            function () {
                if (!$(this).prev().hasClass('input-ghost')) {
                    var element = $("<input type='file' class='input-ghost' style='visibility:hidden; height:0'>");
                    element.attr("name", $(this).attr("name"));
                    element.change(function () {
                        element.next(element).find('input').val((element.val()).split('\\').pop());
                    });
                    $(this).find("button.btn-choose").click(function () {
                        element.click();
                    });
                    $(this).find("button.btn-reset").click(function () {
                        element.val(null);
                        $(this).parents(".input-file").find('input').val('');
                    });
                    $(this).find('input').css("cursor", "pointer");
                    $(this).find('input').mousedown(function () {
                        $(this).parents('.input-file').prev().click();
                        return false;
                    });
                    return element;
                }
            }
        );
    }
    $(function () {
        bs_input_file();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Am I missing something or is this falsely tagged as c#?

Comment: @IDarkCoder I can't see anything to do with C# as well, but this happens (surprisingly/ sadly often, seen like 5 today already), we just edit away the tag

Comment: Sorry, originally had a C # code, but I removed it because it was not needed, but forgot to remove the tag